# React: Function arguments are HTML elements

Tags: reactjs, function, arguments

I am having weird problem using "npx create-react-app" and "d3-fetch". The code below should give tsv data as an output but it print rows from public/index.html. This code works in my other react apps which haven't been built by using "npx create-react-app"

My code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {tsv} from 'd3-fetch';

export default class App extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        tsv('data/data.tsv', function(d) {
          console.log(d)
        }).then()
    }

  render() {

    return (
      <h1>hi</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

Output should print data but it gives html elements for console.log:

```
{<!DOCTYPE html>: "<html lang="en">"}
{<!DOCTYPE html>: "  <head>"}
{<!DOCTYPE html>: "    <meta charset="utf-8">"}
...
```

Comment: Hey! I don't know what d3-fetch is, but it's seems to me, it's fetching something from network. The answer it gets, probably error of some kind, and server returns html answer... Did you look in Network requests in DevTools? What code server returns?

Comment: maybe the path 'data/data.tsv' is unknown for the app. Have you tried relative path? e.g.  '../../data/data.tsv'. You can configure absolute path using an .env file - https://medium.com/@ktruong008/absolute-imports-with-create-react-app-4338fbca7e3d

Comment: This isn't d3-fetch related problem. Looking at network requests got me closer. Data.tsv has the same content as index.html. The index.html page is in every possible url. http://localhost:3000/ loads the same page as http://localhost:3000/goirjaoi Can you guys help me to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: I didn't fully understand how React-create-app works. I managed to get data  work after converting it to json file. Not optimal since I like csv data but have to live with it.

import data from './data/data.json';

Answer (score 0):

The solution was converting csv data manually to json. Then get json data

```
import data from './data/data.json';
```